# do we have possibility to limit amount of charecter in long text?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I want to write a comment in one feild which has more than 255 charecter I define long text as data type . do we have possibilty to put limitation for it , I mean give a feild size to it? for example up to 2000

Answer (score 0):

No.

But you can use the *BeforeUpdate* event in your form to *cancel* the update if the text is longer than your 2000 characters.

Comment: A Before Change [data macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200) should be able to do it, too.